# Duplicate mysql entries with unique indexes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a rails application with ~20,000 users and four application servers.  During the process of troubleshooting an unrelated issue, I discovered some (mostly) duplicate rows in the database.  Here's an example

```
select transaction_uid,created_at,data from my_table where user_uid=23;
```

which returns something similar to this:

```
|9004  | 2015-01-19 21:17:05 | "data"
|12052 | 2015-01-21 14:11:27 | "abc"
|12053 | 2015-01-21 14:11:27 | "abc"
```

The problem is in the last two rows - the uids are sequential, the time stamps are identical (or one second different, at the most), and the data is identical.

At first I thought this was a front-end issue - maybe a user was double clicking a submit button and the use case which handles this insertion was being called twice - after all it's not *really* a duplicate as the uid (which is generated by mysql) is unique.

Many 'puts' statements and stacktraces later, I'm fairly sure that is not the case.  My best guess is that it's an issue with having multiple application servers, and since it's not majorly affecting the application in a negative way, I would leave it with that explanation and move on - but there's something that's a little funny.  Here are the users affected by this:

```
user_uid    duplicate transaction uid
1893        3884
2015        1332, 1592
2328        1736, 1759
2484        12499
2941        5728
368         1318
3897        2924, 3032, 4340
4581        4390, 4437, 6462, 13485
5199        5047, 7955, 13609
5639        6113, 6130, 13450, 14927
6082        11878, 13213, 14324
6673        6421
6760        12359
7761        12053, 13261
```

So 14 users in an application with ~20k.  Objectively not a big issue - but if this were just an issue stemming from multiple application servers, I would expect it to affect users randomly.  However of the users affected, just over half have been affected more than once, many of them affected multiple times.  After seeing this, it made me rethink the possibility of this being introduced via the front-end - maybe users 4581 and 5639 are professional Starcraft players?

It's weird enough that I don't feel comfortable just chalking it up to multiple app servers.  Anyone else ever come across this?

**edit**
After speaking with the lead front-end developer, I've learned that all interactive elements use AJAX and are locked until they receive a message from the server.  So it is actually impossible for this to be coming from users in the front-end.

Comment: What's the unique index on? `created_at,data`?

Comment: from a migration (using Sequel):  `add_index [:transaction_uid, :user_uid], :unique => true`

Comment: If `transaction_uid` is an autoincrement, I'm not sure why you bothered to add the index. Chances are the users are just clicking submit repeatedly before the next page loads.

Comment: Can you check user's navigator? Maybe these are using some strange version....

Comment: @OscarPérez, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @ceejayoz, spoke to the lead front-end designer, they said that all interactive elements use ajax and are locked until the server responds - so it's actually impossible for this to be done by the user in the front-end

Comment: @dax what I mean is that maybe some users use a web browser that executes Javascript in an odd way... Maybe they're not blocking Ajax requests as you expect. Could you contact these users and ask them what browser are they using? Maybe you could add some log messages to your app...

Comment: @OscarPérez, I store the user_agent at login for statistics (and for this sort of thing) - all of them are using modern browsers with recent OS's.  No weirdos :p

Comment: @dax, ok. Had to check...